# Office.js Word: Inserting columns in tables now results in ItemNotFound

Tags: ms-word, office-js

The code below produces an "ItemNotFound" error on the line indicated.  Until recently, I believe it worked fine.
If I comment out the "addCoumns" line (and make rowsToAdd=0), there is no error.

Background:  I have many tables in Word docs.  All tables are in Content Controls.  My code loops through the tables and updates values (based on Excel data).  Before it updates the values, it often inserts/deletes rows/columns so the tables match the size of the source data (Excel ranges).
Note: I loop through each cell because it is much faster than setting the entire table from a 2D array (especially if not all cells need to be updated).

How can modify the code to avoid errors?  I think my getFirst… getNext… approach is not the best.

Run in Script Lab:

```js
$("#run").click(updateTables);
//first insert a table inside a content control
function updateTables() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var CCs = context.document.contentControls;
        context.load(CCs, "tag, id");
        return context.sync().then(function () {
        var myTable = CCs.items[0].tables.getFirst();
        var arrValues = myTable.load("values");
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            var rowsToAdd = 1;
            var colsToAdd = 1;
            var rows = arrValues.values.length + rowsToAdd;
            var cols = arrValues.values[0].length + colsToAdd;
            CCs.items[0].tables.getFirst().addRows("end", rowsToAdd);
            CCs.items[0].tables.getFirst().addColumns("end", colsToAdd);       
            return context.sync().then(function () {    
                var tCell;  
                //ItemNotFound error occurs on this line:
                var tRow = CCs.items[0].tables.getFirst().rows.getFirst(); 
                for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                    tCell = tRow.cells.getFirst();
                    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                        tCell.value = 'r' + row + ':c' + col;;
                        if (col < cols - 1) {
                            tCell = tCell.getNext();
                        }
                    }
                    if (row < rows - 1) {
                        tRow = tRow.getNext();
                    }
                }
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    console.log("Done");

                });
            });
        });
        });
    })
        .catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Word freezes with deleteColumns or deleteRows.  Usually similar behavior on Mac vs Windows.

Comment: I am curious to find out which method throws the 'ItemNotFound' exception. You have two getFirst() calls on that line, which could both be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Super interesting problem i need to investigate in more detail why your script is behaving like this.
But in the meantime, I created a typescript equivalent of your code, please give it a try i think it solves the problem.

https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/f40eab599d7fc7b95a1f942a689ef243

Comment: It does solve the inserting problem.  However, deleting rows or columns still freezes Word.

Comment: ok let me check that, this was not in your original sample :)